# JavaScript and AngularJS testing - Karma, Jasmine, karma-jasmine, etc

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm preparing some curriculum for students at a bootcamp, and this is my first exposure to testing in general, let alone testing in Angular. I've been researching a lot of stuff, but thought I could get some definitive answers from the community:

I'm still a little hazy on how Karma and Jasmine work together. I understand that Karma is a test runner and Jasmine is the framework that includes assertions, describe blocks, etc. But what is the best/preferred way to install these to start including testing in an Angular app? I've done `npm install --save-dev karma`, run `karma init` and set all the settings, and downloaded Jasmine from their releases page, but I'm not exactly sure how to integrate these into a new or existing Angular application. The Jasmine Standalone seems to have its own organization that requires you to move all your source files to their `src` folder, but that seems ridiculous unless you're just testing vanilla JavaScript (which I'm guessing is what the Jasmine standalone version is for?)

I also saw in the Angular docs on testing a reference to `karma-jasmine`, which I'm not 100% sure how that plays in with karma and jasmine as separate entities.

Any guidance or help for a testing beginner would be greatly appreciated. I've spent hours researching and am still a bit confused on all of it. Sorry if these questions are dumb, I'm really new to the whole concept.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing? Have you looked at the angular-seed project example, linked at the end of the page? All you need is `npm install karma` followed by `./node_modules/karma/bin/karma init`. Answer the questions, choose jasmine as test framework, choose all the locations to your JS and test files (and the files of angular, angular-mocks, etc.), and write tests as explained in the developer guide. Then run them using `./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js`